# Telegraf SNMP plugin Error: IF-MIB::ifTable: Unknown Object Identifier

Tags: amazon-ec2, snmp, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin

Steps followed to installed SNMP manager and agent on ec2

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install snmp snmp-mibs-downloader
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install snmpd
```

I opened `sudo nano /etc/snmp/snmp.conf` and commented the following line:

```
#mibs :
```

Then I went into the configuration file and modified file as below:

```
sudo nano /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
```

```
Listen for connections from the local system only
agentAddress  udp:127.0.0.1:161  <--- commented this part.
Listen for connections on all interfaces (both IPv4 and IPv6)
agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161  <--remove the comment from this line to make it work.
```

using below command I can get snmp data

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1 .
```

From inside docker container as well I can get the data

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c public host.docker.internal .
```

Docker-compose:

```
telegraf_snmp:
    image: telegraf:1.22.1
    container_name: telegraf_snmp
    restart: always
    depends_on:
        - influxdb
    networks:
      - analytics
    extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    # ports:
    #   - "161:161/udp"
    volumes:
      - /mnt/telegraf/snmp:/var/lib/telegraf
      - ./etc/telegraf/snmp/:/etc/telegraf/snmp/
    env_file:
      - secrets.env
    environment:
        INFLUXDB_URL: http://influxdb:8086
    command:
        --config-directory /etc/telegraf/snmp/telegraf.d
        --config /etc/telegraf/snmp/telegraf.conf
    links:
      - influxdb
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
```

Telegraf Input conf:

```
[[inputs.snmp]]
  ## Agent addresses to retrieve values from.
  ##   format:  agents = ["<scheme://><hostname>:<port>"]
  ##   scheme:  optional, either udp, udp4, udp6, tcp, tcp4, tcp6.  
  ##            default is udp
  ##   port:    optional
  ##   example: agents = ["udp://127.0.0.1:161"]
  ##            agents = ["tcp://127.0.0.1:161"]
  ##            agents = ["udp4://v4only-snmp-agent"]
  # agents = ["udp://127.0.0.1:161"]
  agents = ["udp://host.docker.internal:161"]

  ## Timeout for each request.
  timeout = "15s"

  ## SNMP version; can be 1, 2, or 3.
  version = 2

  ## SNMP community string.
  community = "public"

  ## Agent host tag
  # agent_host_tag = "agent_host"

  ## Number of retries to attempt.
  retries = 3

  ## The GETBULK max-repetitions parameter.
  # max_repetitions = 10

  ## SNMPv3 authentication and encryption options.
  ##
  ## Security Name.
  # sec_name = "myuser"
  ## Authentication protocol; one of "MD5", "SHA", or "".
  # auth_protocol = "MD5"
  ## Authentication password.
  # auth_password = "pass"
  ## Security Level; one of "noAuthNoPriv", "authNoPriv", or "authPriv".
  # sec_level = "authNoPriv"
  ## Context Name.
  # context_name = ""
  ## Privacy protocol used for encrypted messages; one of "DES", "AES", "AES192", "AES192C", "AES256", "AES256C", or "".
  ### Protocols "AES192", "AES192", "AES256", and "AES256C" require the underlying net-snmp tools 
  ### to be compiled with --enable-blumenthal-aes (http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/INSTALL.html)
  # priv_protocol = ""
  ## Privacy password used for encrypted messages.
  # priv_password = ""

  ## Add fields and tables defining the variables you wish to collect.  This
  ## example collects the system uptime and interface variables.  Reference the
  ## full plugin documentation for configuration details.
  [[inputs.snmp.field]]
    oid = "RFC1213-MIB::sysUpTime.0"
    name = "uptime"

  [[inputs.snmp.field]]
    oid = "RFC1213-MIB::sysName.0"
    name = "source"
    is_tag = true

  [[inputs.snmp.table]]
    oid = "IF-MIB::ifTable"
    name = "interface"
    inherit_tags = ["source"]

    [[inputs.snmp.table.field]]
      oid = "IF-MIB::ifDescr"
      name = "ifDescr"
      is_tag = true
```

Telegraf logs:

```
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
IF-MIB::ifTable: Unknown Object Identifier: exit status 2
2022-09-09T10:10:09Z I! Starting Telegraf 1.22.1
2022-09-09T10:10:09Z I! Loaded inputs: snmp
2022-09-09T10:10:09Z I! Loaded aggregators:
2022-09-09T10:10:09Z I! Loaded processors:
2022-09-09T10:10:09Z I! Loaded outputs: file influxdb_v2
2022-09-09T10:10:09Z I! Tags enabled: host=7a38697f4527
2022-09-09T10:10:09Z I! [agent] Config: Interval:10s, Quiet:false, Hostname:"7a38697f4527", Flush Interval:10s
2022-09-09T10:10:09Z E! [telegraf] Error running agent: could not initialize input inputs.snmp: initializing table interface: translating: MIB search path: /root/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
IF-MIB::ifTable: Unknown Object Identifier: exit status 2
2022-09-09T10:10:11Z I! Starting Telegraf 1.22.1
2022-09-09T10:10:11Z I! Loaded inputs: snmp
2022-09-09T10:10:11Z I! Loaded aggregators:
2022-09-09T10:10:11Z I! Loaded processors:
2022-09-09T10:10:11Z I! Loaded outputs: file influxdb_v2
2022-09-09T10:10:11Z I! Tags enabled: host=7a38697f4527
2022-09-09T10:10:11Z I! [agent] Config: Interval:10s, Quiet:false, Hostname:"7a38697f4527", Flush Interval:10s
2022-09-09T10:10:11Z E! [telegraf] Error running agent: could not initialize input inputs.snmp: initializing table interface: translating: MIB search path: /root/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
IF-MIB::ifTable: Unknown Object Identifier: exit status 2
```

But in telegraf I get above error.
I checked the mibs directory using `ls /usr/share/snmp/mibs`

[image]

I cannot find IF-MIB file here even after installing

```
$ sudo apt-get install snmp-mibs-downloader
$ sudo download-mibs
```

How can I resolve this issue ? Do I need to follow some additional steps ?

SNMP Plugin in telegraf should able to pull the data from SNMP